# Delete mails from send mail mailing queue

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I need to delete mails from my centos mailing queue.I'm using sendMail as MTA. I used the following command which I found by searching:
cd /var/spool/mail
rm -f *

But nothing happened to my mailing queue.
And one more thing that if I want to delete mails by subject wise.

Answer (score 6):

This may help:

```
postsuper -d ALL deferred
```

To delete matching expressions in email, check this script: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-postfix-flush-mail-queue.html

Comment: worked for me, on CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

Comment: That's a command for Postfix. In Sendmail you have to use the tool `qtool.pl`.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have /var/spool/mqueue either.

To remove the mailq in centos if you are using postfix

```
    rm -rf /var/spool/postfix/defer/*
    rm -rf /var/spool/postfix/deferred/*
```

Answer (score 2):

You have removed the wrong folder. You should remove */var/spool/mqueue/* to flush your mail queue

Comment: Yes, I have got the same problem and there is no directory named mqueue

Comment: I also don't have it. So "postsuper -d ALL" helped

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be a little bit late, but what about

```
mailq
```

to get the message-id and

```
sendmail -Mrm <message-id>
```

to remove the message from the queue without further notice?

Comment: Perfect for if you just want to delete one mail

Answer (score -1):

Use

> postsuper -d ALL

to remove all mails from queue
But use only if you know that emails are spam.